# Possible use of "sie" in context of objects rather than women

Tags: translation, german-to-english

[In this link](https://youtu.be/bS_X2NEitTY?t=6m56s), there are three sentences:

> Where is the bag? ("wo ist die Tasche?")
>   Is it still in Berlin? ("Ist **sie** noch in Berlin?")

I dont understand why they have used *sie* to refer to bag? I think it should be some feminine word for `es`.

Comment: Because it's _die Tasche_, i.e. female. You use _er_, _sie_ and _es_ with persons and objects alike, depending on the article.

Comment: "Some feminine word for *es*" **is** *sie*. The male personal pronoun is *er*: *Wo ist der Koffer? Ist er noch in Berlin?*

Comment: Und der Vollständigkeit halber: Wo ist das Etui? Ist es noch In Frankfurt?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

»Sie« is the pronoun for feminine words.
»Die Tasche« is feminine (its article in nominative singular is »die«). So, if you use a pronoun to refer to a female word like »die Tasche«, then you have to use the female pronoun »sie«.

Also remember:
Not the thing itself is female. The word is female. The words »Auto«, »Wagen« and »Karre« are German synonyms for the same thing (the car). But they have different genders:

> male: **Der Wagen** dort drüben ist rot. **Er** gehört mir.
>   female: **Die Karre** dort drüben ist rot. **Sie** gehört mir.
>   neuter: **Das Auto** dort drüben ist rot. **Es** gehört mir.

All three sentences are in English:

> **The car** over there is red. **It** belongs to me.

And because it's not the thing that has a gramatical gender, but the word, there are words for persons that do not have the same gender as the person itself: The German word for »girl« (»Mädchen«) is *not* female. It is neuter:

> **Das** Mädchen ist hübsch. **Es** hat lange blonde Haare.
>   The girl is pretty. She has long blond hair.

Comment: **But** notice that many German speakers will by now consider that last example old-fashioned and use ‘das Mädchen ist hübsch. *Sie* hat lange, blonde Haare.’ +1